# Error incorrect select list on query?

Tags: coldfusion, qoq

I have three queries:

```
<cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="getNotApproved">
  select submitterdept, COUNT(*) AS 'not_approved_manager'
  from [Intranet].[dbo].[CSEReduxResponses]
   where status =0 and approveddate is null
   group by submitterdept
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="GetDepartments">
        SELECT *
        FROM CSEReduxDepts

</cfquery>
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="final_approved">
    select dep.csedept_id,DEP.csedept_name, COUNT(*) AS 'not_approved_manager'
from GetDepartments dep
join getNotApproved cs on cs.submitterdept = dep.csedept_id
where approveddate is null
group by dep.csedept_ID, dep.csedept_name
</cfquery>
```

When I run them on a cfm file it gives me a error:

```
Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "\'not_approved_manager\'. Incorrect Select List,
```

which is on line  `<cfquery dbtype="query" name="final_approved">`
I know these queries work because I have run them on my microsoft sql server 2008, they show me the correct output , all three running.
So I'm trying to figure out why it doesnt work on coldfusion.

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes from your names in your Select list?

Comment: i get a different error: Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "dep.

Comment: Might not support aliasing for table names

Comment: @math reason is because i do use getdepartments somewhere else too

Comment: really that could be umm , i use coldfusion 9

Comment: @mattbusche not sure what you are suggesting

Comment: Run your combined query and run your other query separately. Don't use query of query because it doesn't save you anything

Comment: Why are you using a query of queries for this? You can combine all three of those `cfquery` calls into one by using `JOIN` in the actual DBMS. QoQ is nice, but it is not best option here. Let the DB handle retrieving data, that is what it is designed for.

Comment: @scott being new to this still learning, i got it to work this way, i will try to do it into one, so to answer your question i didnt know what other way to do it

Comment: It is all good. You should be able to use `JOIN` in the new query you write and I bet it is more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query of queries does not support the keyword "join".  So, in addition to the other things going on, this:

```
from GetDepartments dep
join getNotApproved cs on cs.submitterdept = dep.csedept_id
```

has to become something like this:

```
from GetDepartments dep, getNotApproved cs 
where cs.submitterdept = dep.csedept_id
```

As mentioned in the comments, alias names for tables might not be supported.

Comment: Use of QoQ here is not advised. You can condense all 2 `cfquery` calls into 1 and let the database (whose job it is to handle data like this) do its job